# `notify-send` works when invoking script manually, but not from a crontab

Tags: bash, cron, notify-send

I wanted my cron job to report to me on desktop when it executes, through `notify-send` command on Ubuntu. I've read through the common problems that stated a shell script didn't have access to a display, which is solved by adding this before calling `notify-send`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

So i am okay in that regard.

The place where i am right now, is that my script works and notifies me on desktop if i invoke it from terminal manually, but not from the `crontab`.

The situation is as follows:

1. The script that executes is a PHP file. The PHP command to invoke the shell command, is:

```php
<?php
`export DISPLAY=:0.0 && command -v notify-send && notify-send "Hello world"`;
```

(backticks in PHP mean execute in shell)

2. In both cases i am running it as `root`
3. When testing from terminal, i run:

```sh
sudo -u root /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/cron.php &> /dev/null
```

This works, and i get a desktop notification

4. To edit my `crontab` for the `root` user, i use:

```sh
sudo -u root crontab -e
```

5. In my `crontab` file, my line is this:

```sh
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/cron.php &> /dev/null
```

This one does not produce a desktop notification, even though the script 100% executes (i have the successful result in log files).

What goes wrong here, and why wouldn't i get the desktop notification?

Comment: I'd recommend to place your script in a `.sh` file and add the `export PATH=$PATH:...`  in the beginning of the file. Hopefully then it should be able to execute it from the  crontab.

Answer (score 0):

you must set the PATH within the script or export it from crontab!

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```